How do I plot 1/x in Julia?
This seems like a very simple thing to do but the normal methods don't work for me. I want to plot f(x)=1/x. Here is my code:
using Plots
f(x) = 1/x

plot(f)

The plot looks like this right now:


the plotting is correct, you might want to adjust the scaling to zoom around [0,0]

@PA is right, the plotting is correct but the plot limits were too large. This zooms it in:
using Plots
f(x) = 1/x
plot(f, plot_title="f(x) = 1/x", xlims=(-5,5), ylims=(-5,5))

